# Using boost::indirect_iterator

Tags: boost

When trying to use **boost::indirect_iterator** I am getting "int is not a class, struct, or union type".
Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

#include <boost/iterator/indirect_iterator.hpp>

// Expose the itererator if the container stores pointers.
class MyCollection
{
public:
  // Iterator interface
  typedef boost::indirect_iterator<int*> iterator;

  iterator begin() { return objects.begin(); }

  iterator end() { return objects.end(); }

private:

  std::set<int*> objects;
};

int main()
{
  MyCollection myCollection;

  for(MyCollection::iterator iterator = myCollection.begin(); iterator != myCollection.end(); iterator++)
  {
    std::cout << " " << *iterator;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: typedef boost::indirect_iterator<std::set<int*>::iterator> iterator;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out you have to use:

```
typedef boost::indirect_iterator<std::set<int*>::iterator> iterator;
```